# Importing from another project in pydev

Tags: pydev

I've been looking around for quite some time but I just can't find the answer.  Similar questions relate to some tricky cases with third party libraries and all, but my situation seems to be textbook-simple.  Nevertheless I can't figure out how this works.

I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2, Pydev 2.2.0, running on an Ubuntu 11.04 machine.

My case seems simple: I want to write a package as its own project, and then I want to write an application using this package in another project.

How should I setup pydev so that I can have this two projects "core" (the package) and "app" (which uses the core package), and from within "app" do:

```
import core
```

?

- I have added core to the Project References of app but it doesn't do
  anything.
- I have added /core/ to the Source folders (I had to force for that because is was not
  showing in the list), it didn't work (so I removed it).
- I have added /full/path/to/core to the External Libraries, it still doesn't work.

By "doesn't work", I mean that I get an "unresolved import: core", always.

Ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Provided you have 2 projects with the PYTHONPATH properly set (through source folders), it should work just adding a project reference.

Maybe an example can help...

E.g.:

```
project1
project1/src <-- this should be set as the source folder
project1/src/core
project1/src/core/__init__.py

project2
project2/src <-- this should be set as the source folder
project2/src/app
project2/src/app/__init__.py
```

and then edit the project2 properties > project references and select 'project1' to be able to access the project1 from the project2.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work now!  1) I do not need to add anything from project1 in the pythonpath or source folders of project 2.  2) Naming my project "core" is not enough even if it has a __init__.py: I need a proper package "core".  3) Also, restarting eclipse (file/restart) was necessary.  Yay!

Answer (score 2):

I had been in same problem for a while.
Now I figured it out how I can import class or function from module and package in other projects.
I found myself dumb from this because it is ever easy.

**Conclusion!**
All you have to do is just to check the project name in 'Project References', File/Properties/Project References.
In terms of import usage, referencing other project is same as you put all files or modules in your current project directory.
I am using liclipse_1.0.0_win32.x86_64 on Windows 7.

Let's me show examples.
There are two project A and B and the project A has module a1.py and package 'M'.
You are working on B project and check reference A project in following project tree.

```
|-- A
|   |-- M
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- m1.py
|   `-- a1.py
`-- B
    `-- b1.py

# a1.py
def say_a():
    print "I'm A"

# m1.py
def say_m():
    print "I'm M"
```

Now you can access project A like following.

```
#b1.py
import a1
from M import m1   
a1.say_a()
m1.say_m()
```

In fact python import statement is little bit odd for me that you can find other way to do same thing.
In addition, if you want to run b1.py from Linux command line see this.

> ~/tmp/pydemo/B$ PYTHONPATH=../A python b1.py

Answer (score 0):

I did not get this working by adding a project reference. However, I got it working by first removing and then adding the pydev project nature to the project, and then, set the project reference.