# How to use a package from another project in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pythonpath

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956157/importing-from-another-project-in-pydev/7961179#7961179), but it didn't work for me.

These are the steps I used:

1. Right-click project1 > Properties > Project References > select project2R
2. Right-click project1 >
   Properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH > Add source folder, but project2 is not listed

If I add project2 manually to `.pydevproject`, it replaces `project2\src` with `project1\src`.

This is really driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the path to the folder **containing** any package you wish to use into your PYTHONPATH environment variable (create a new one if there isn't one already) and voilá!

For instance, suppose you have a package named "foo" in a directory "/path/to/project/src/foo".
Simply append "/path/to/project/src" (note that I left "foo" out of the path because that's our package) to PYTHONPATH and then open an interpreter and try "import foo". This should work both on Windows and Linux too ;)